# iPhone App Binary rejected in-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have submitted  an iphone app with in-app purchase But my Binary is rejected and i have got the following message from apple

From Apple.
Missing IAPs

We are unable to complete the review of your app since one or more of your In App Purchases have not been submitted for review.

Please be sure to take action and submit your In App Purchases AND upload a new binary in iTunes Connect. Learn more about submitting In App Purchases for review in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.

Once you've submitted your In App Purchases and uploaded a new binary, we can proceed with your review.

Please tell me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to submit the In App Purchase which will be available in `itunesconnect.apple.com->manage application-> your application`
here you can find as shown in the picture [image]

Now go to Manage in-App Purchases and click create New. Give your product Id and type of IAP after creating it shows `waiting for review` then submit your binary again

Answer (score 1):

In your iTunes Connect account, go to your application page and click on "Manage in-app purchases", then add the in-app purchase and submit it for review.

[image]

[image]